# ReferenceError: [...] document is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, d3.js, ejs

I would like to display data with a chart on a html page. For this project I used the following: Node.js, Express.js, D3, EJS.
The node page serves an initial html page where the user is prompted to insert some data. This values are submitted to the node server (as a post request) and based on this input I would fetch a dataset from an API. Now the fetching in the node server works perfectly fine. My problem is displaying this data with a chart to the user. In order to do so I've used EJS.(Please see code below). Whenever I receive a post request the following (should) execute:

1. Reception of data from user (works fine)
2. Fetching of data from API (works fine)
3. Render graph.html view along with data to be displayed in chart. (doesn't work)

Unfortunately every attempt at executing the client side script (chart.js) -script included in graph.html - results in the following error:

```
ReferenceError: C:\pweb\tools\XAMPP\htdocs\latency\graph.html:12
    10|     <div id='myDiv0'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>

    11|     <div id='myDiv1'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>

 >> 12|     <%- getGraph('myDiv0', data, 1, 'RTT') %>

    13|     <%- getGraph('myDiv1', data, 2, 'COF') %>

    14|     <script type="module" src="chart.js"></script>

    15| </body>


document is not defined
    at Object.getGraph (C:\pweb\tools\XAMPP\htdocs\latency\chart.js:18:23)
    at eval ("C:\\pweb\\tools\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\latency\\graph.html":12:17)
    at graph (C:\pweb\tools\XAMPP\htdocs\latency\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\pweb\tools\XAMPP\htdocs\latency\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\pweb\tools\XAMPP\htdocs\latency\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\pweb\tools\XAMPP\htdocs\latency\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\pweb\tools\XAMPP\htdocs\latency\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (C:\pweb\tools\XAMPP\htdocs\latency\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\pweb\tools\XAMPP\htdocs\latency\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at C:\pweb\tools\XAMPP\htdocs\latency\index.js:173:9
```

Here are parts of the code I think may cause the problem:

1. Server (node.js)

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const express = require('express')
const ejs = require('ejs')
const chart = require('./chart.js')

const app = express();

app.engine('.html', ejs.__express);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.urlencoded( {extended: true} ));
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.locals.getGraph = chart;

async function fetchData(){...}

app.post('/', async function(req,res){

    let dataset = await fetchData();
    res.render('graph', {data: dataset});
});


app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started at http://localhost:' + port);
```

2. graph.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.14.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv0'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
    <div id='myDiv1'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
    <%- getGraph('myDiv0', data, 1, 'RTT') %>
    <%- getGraph('myDiv1', data, 2, 'COF') %>
    <script type="module" src="chart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

3. chart.js

```js
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const d3 = Object.assign({}, require('d3-selection'), require('d3-time-format'), 
                          require('d3-scale'), require('d3-array'), require('d3-axis'),
                          require('d3-shape'));

const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
//const document = new JSDOM().window.document;

function getGraph(where, dataset, y_index){
        ...
}

module.exports = getGraph;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Even suggestions of different implementations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error says something about line `18` in `chart.js`

Comment: yes. In line 18 is referenced document

Comment: You can't run frontend script in the backend

Comment: Ok..but how can I get chart.js to run on the frontend then?

Comment: Run it inside `script` tag. Without `<%-`